# How can I open a bank account in Spain with an EU (Hungarian) passport

Tags: bank-account, european-union, spain, hungary

I am an EU citizen (Hungarian) and would like to open a bank account in Spain.

Question:

1. Is it enough to show my EU passport or do they require anything else?
2. Do I need to show proof of a spanish address (what kind of document)?
3. Do I need to show proof of a spanish job (what kind of document)?